# Is there a command to open a folder in a window from the command line in Windows (like "open" on MacOS X)?

Tags: windows, command-line, shortcuts

Like [this](https://superuser.com/questions/116142/open-a-directory-in-a-linux-gui-file-browser-via-the-command-line) but for Windows. Preferably from Cygwin, and with relative paths

```
$ open ./
```

Comment: FYI, for more on `open` on OS X, check out http://superuser.com/questions/4368/os-x-equivalent-of-windows-run-box/4383#4383

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To launch the current directory:

From cmd.exe, you can just type `start .` to launch Explorer.

If you use PowerShell, you can use `invoke-item .` or the alias `ii .`

You can replace "." with any directory path.

Comment: `explorer .` would be the explicit variant

Comment: `explorer /e,.` if you want the tree on the left.